# ngIf* comaparison with Or (||) not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I have a siple ngIf* as below

```
<td *ngIf="rowData.statusObj?.id != 30 " [colSpan] = "1">
                        <a pTooltip="Delete" tooltipPosition="top" title="Delete" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="delete(rowData.id)"><img src="{{imgUrl}}icon_delete_new.gif"/></a> 
                    </td>
                    <td *ngIf="rowData.statusObj?.id == 30" [colSpan] = "1"></td>
```

This works fine. I would like to add another condition like below

```
<td *ngIf="rowData.statusObj?.id != 30 || rowData.statusObj?.id != 40 " [colSpan] = "1">
                        <a pTooltip="Delete" tooltipPosition="top" title="Delete" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="delete(rowData.id)"><img src="{{imgUrl}}icon_delete_new.gif"/></a> 
                    </td>
                    <td *ngIf="rowData.statusObj?.id == 30 || rowData.statusObj?.id == 40" [colSpan] = "1"></td>
```

This doesnt work for the 1st td. I can see the delete button as well the empty td. What is wrong and how should ngIf* be handled here? suggestions pls.

Comment: you need and not or i believe```rowData.statusObj?.id != 30 && rowData.statusObj?.id != 4```

Comment: @Eugen Sunic it cannot be 30 & 40 same time or for same row element

Comment: read my comment again and evaluate it

Comment: @JPNW the condition on the first line is a negation (NOT A). When you add a "OR" to your condition (last line: A OR B), the negation of it (NOT (A OR B)) is the same as ((NOT A) AND (NOT B)). (so, I believe Eugen's comment is right on the point, and concerns the first line)

Comment: @Pac0 !(a || b)=== !a  &&!b  this is demorgans and is equal

Comment: @EugenSunic Yes, I agree with you, I'm trying to point it out to OP ;) .